# Writing a 2-D array to Excel

Tags: excel, datanitro

Is there a good way to write a 2-D array to a table in DataNitro? I'm working on a basic sudoku solver in Excel and would rather use python than VisualBasic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use the table cell property - we just added this in our last update.

For example:

```
x = [[6, 7, '', 2, 3, '', '', '', ''], ... ['', '', '', '', 6, 8, '', 3, 2]] 
# the sudoku puzzle, written out row boy row
Cell("A1").table = x
```

Source: I'm one of the DataNitro developers.